# How could I detect my cat from 1 meter away?

Tags: rf, rfid, mfrc522

I am building an automated pet feeding system. One of the functions has to be that the system detects that the pet is near. I was thinking of using an RC-522 RFID, but the range on that is 10 cm maximum. What would you use that would have a range of 1 meter minimum?

The thing is, I want to use the system in my backyard and I don't want the neighbours' cats to use my feeder. I need a solution to detect that my cat is 1 meter or more away from it.

Comment: There are UHF tags with a much longer range, though I believe readers are a lot more expensive, and I have no idea whether it's possible to track distance accurately in that range. You could also look into UWB. Or even BLE.

Comment: I changed the title so that it actually says what the question is about.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just put a tag-reading cat-flap on your back door?

Comment: I don't want to go Pavlov on your cat, but wouldn't a 10cm-range tag be nice? You could train your cat that if she or he wants food, the little red LED must be on, and then she can press her neck (with the collar with the tag) against a specific rectangle, and that will release the food? That way, you would even avoid that your cat starts staying within that 1m radius all time, since there won't be food without the visual cue.

Comment: I like the Bluetooth idea.  It'd be a low power solution.  One could perhaps look at signal strength to infer a set minimum distance (though I have never looked into that for reliability).  TI used to have a Bluetooth module dev kit that included an additional Bluetooth dongle (with coin cell battery).  That might be worth a look.

Comment: To add to the other ideas (and this is lots cheaper, if it works -- TBD) one might consider winding up metal detector coils and a circuit. Assuming that cat would allow an appropriate name tag of some kind on a collar. Should be tunable for reasonably low levels of false positives.

Comment: Oh, by the way, in some countries, some pets and other animales are required to be "chipped" and have an RFID implant. More common for dogs than cats, though, and I believe the range should not be much better than 13.56 MHz RFID.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a bit on options described in comments:

- There are UHF RFID tags which can be read at much longer distances. However the reader is much more expensive, and I have no idea what kind of accuracy one could get at those distances.
- BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) is probably the simplest and cheapest. Have your pet wear a beacon which advertises its presence every second or so, and some kind of scanner on the pet feeding system (any ESP32-based board should do, but there are lots of other options).

  Measure the RSSI (signal strength), and find a good cut-off value for "close enough". It won't be very accurate, but with a bit of trial and error you should be able to find a good trade-off. Don't forget to test it in real conditions (i.e. with the cat actually wearing it).

  More recent BLE implementations can do more accurate distance measurement (based on round-trip time rather than signal strength), but I have no idea what energy impact that would have and if there are any simple (and cheap and small) beacons that would support it.

  Beacons come in all shapes and sizes, down to quite small coin-cell operated beacons. Battery life is limited, but is highly dependent on advertising rate. An advertising interval of a second or two should be more than enough and even on a coin cell should get at least months, possibly a year of two, of battery life.

  However, even the smaller beacons are still quite larger and heavier than an RFID tag (mostly due to the battery). Finding the right beacon is probably the biggest challenge.
- UWB should give you a more precise range, but relevant hardware is still uncommon and expensive. Also not sure if this can actually be used on a periodic basis (like BLE advertisements). I believe Apple's AirTags mostly used BLE, and only switch to UWB for direction/distance finding when needed.
- You can implant an RFID microchip directly in your cat, if it doesn't already have one. This is actually mandatory for dogs in many countries, less often for cats (but still possible). This requires a specific type of reader, but I don't think it will have a much larger range than 13.56 MHz cards/readers.

  These are so standard that there are pet doors which can detect them, and even [pet feeders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oqtmf5r-PN8), but they definitely require the animal to be much closer than 1 meter. But maybe that's not so bad.

Comment: Could you recommend any specific GPS module with coin cell battery ?

Comment: @Matas a GPS module with a coin cell battery? How is that going to be useful in your scenario? Without additional measures, GPS does not have the required accuracy, and GPS is quite power-hungry, so either you have to take measurements only very infrequently, or on specific events (but if the specific event is "cat moves" then it's useless), or you'll end up with an extremely short battery life. Also even if you have a position, what do you then do with it? Or did you mean a BLE beacon rather than GPS?

Comment: Excusem, I meant BLE module, not GPS.

Comment: @Matas There are lots of cheap coin-cell-powered BLE beacons on Aliexpress and the like. I have an old list which includes Ruuvi, APR Brother, Minew,  Duoweisi... Actual size and battery life can vary quite a bit (coin cells come in very different sizes/capacities, from 230 mAh CR2032 to 1000 mAh CR2477 for instance). Prices range from less than $10 to €30, it's quite possible you'll pay more in shipping than fo the actual device. I haven't used any of the really small and cheap ones (the smallest beacon I've tested must be the Ruuvi which is quite large and expensive in comparison to others).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a link to abbreviations that may not be familiar to everyone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-wideband. It might be possible to use an ultrasonic proximity detector, although it would detect other animals or objects, so might not be suitable. However, it might be used to turn on another sensing system like RFID that would require the cat to get closer, perhaps by activating a lure like a squeaky mouse toy.

Another idea might be to hack an invisible fence collar with the wire buried within a meter of the food dish, and have it activate some means to provide access to your cat. The collar would essentially work in reverse, activating it within the fence. Maybe the collar could have an IR transmitter that would be detected by a receiver in the food dish.